# Android ListView ui theme changes when list is refreshed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-asynctask

I defined an `AsyncTask` to load items into `ListView` dynamically. When I try to fetch next items, the theme that I use(`DarkActionBar`) is changed. So I'm not able to read list items because of transparency. My Android SDK API version is **19.**

```
public class AppSearchActivity extends Activity {

    private int startIndex = 0, listLimit = 10;

    private List < String > listViewItems;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listViewItems = getItems(); // 
        String[] values = StringUtil.convertStringListToArray(listViewItems);
        ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        searchList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private class LoadMoreAsyncTask extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String[] > {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading next 10 apps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String...strings) {
            String query = strings[0];
            startIndex += listLimit;
            List < String > results = PlayStoreUtil.searchAppsByName(query, startIndex, listLimit);
            for (String result: results) {
                listViewItems.add(result);
            }
            return StringUtil.convertStringListToArray(listViewItems);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] array) {
            super.onPostExecute(array);
            ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                array);
            searchList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing " + listViewItems.size() + " apps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshots are added.

**Before**
[image: 1]

**After**
[image: 2]

Comment: If you don't post code, there's nothing we can do. There must be something in your app that changes the style.

Comment: @Christine source code is added..